# Are BTC and Bitcoin Core the same?

Tags: terminology

I recently saw an offer to "Buy Bitcoin Core with your credit card".
Is this "Bitcoin Core" the same thing as BTC?

Comment: Are you referring to this https://buy.bitcoin.com? Either way, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 7):

Kind of. People who call Bitcoin "Bitcoin Core" are referring to Bitcoin. They will also use the name "Bitcoin Legacy". but calling Bitcoin "Bitcoin Core" or "Bitcoin Legacy" is misleading.

Bitcoin Core is the reference client for Bitcoin. But it is wrong and misleading to call a coin by the name of its reference client. For example, we don't call Bitcoin Cash "Bitcoin ABC" even though its reference client is Bitcoin ABC. Nor do we call Ethererum "geth" even though its reference client is Geth.

Answer (score 4):

No, Bitcoin is the token (BTC/XBT), Bitcoin Core is the software used to validate transactions. Calling Bitcoin "Bitcoin core" or "Bitcoin legacy" was a publicity stunt by Roger Ver and Bitcoin Cash to confuse people into thinking Bitcoin cash was Bitcoin, but in reality it was just a fork of the Bitcoin blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin, Bitcoin Core and Bitcoin Legacy are all identifiers for the first Bitcoin (BTC/XBT). Other forks such as Bitcoin Cash, Bitcoin Gold and many other claim to be either the real Bitcoin or a better one. This results in Bitcoin being often referred as Bitcoin Core or Bitcoin Legacy.

Answer (score 1):

While sometimes "Bitcoin Core" is used to refer to Bitcoin, as mentioned in other answers, there is actually also an altcoin that is called "Bitcoin Core (BTCC)". It's currently trading under $1/BTCC, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Bitcoin Core is BTC. This is the original Bitcoin.

The other forks that were created recently are Bitcoin Cash (BCH) and Bitcoin Gold (BTG), among others. Their symbols are different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bitcoin is the same as Bitcoin Core and Bitcoin Legacy. This naming came up because of Bitcoin forks such as Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin Gold.

Also BTC = XBT.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core is what people download on their home computers to run a full node, don’t know exactly what that means but it includes every block of the blockchain. You can create ( or sign or whatever) your own transactions. Well, not me but most everyone else here I’m sure.
BTC is Bitcoin that holds value. It is a token like BCH is Bitcoin Cash

That’s as basic as it gets